# Can't modify global variable in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, global-variables

### **Problem**

I want to have a global counter in react native to show how many notifications a user has in an app that I am creating.

I created a global variabal in a file named global.js:

```
var notifNum = 0;
global.n = notifNum;
```

then in my code, I import it with

```
import './global.js'
```

then later I try to update it with

```
     global.n = notifNum;
```

Notif num being the number of notifications a user has, defined in a function. The problem is that `global.n` stays as 0, and doesn't change at all.

How can I edit the global.n variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has less to do with React-Native and more to do with how javascript works as a language.

In short, you must `export` what you wish to use in other files.

#### Global.js

```
let counter = 0;

const increment = () => {
  counter++;
  console.log('counter_updated', counter);
};

const worker = {
  increment,
  counter
};

module.exports = worker;
```

We've told the JS engine exactly what we want to import in other files. Assigning it to and object and exporting the object is not necessary but allows for cleaner imports/exports IMO.

#### Component.js

```
import { counter, increment } from 'pathTo/global';
```

We deconstruct the object we exported and are now able to modify/use values in the global.js file.

#### Food for thought

This is not an ideal solution as it is not two ways. Incrementing the count in the `global.js` file will not update the value in the `component.js`.

This is because React needs to have it's state updated to initiate a `re-render` of a component.

Also, this will not persist through app reloads, which I believe you would want for something such as notifications.

#### Other solutions

1. Storing the notification counts in a database.
2. Using component `state` to manage the count.
3. Using a state manager like `Redux` or `MobX`

Comment: how do I use the increment and counter? worker.increment; gave me an error, saying can't find variable worker.

Comment: Since we deconstructed the properties from the `worker` object on import, we do not need to reference it with `worker.counter`. Instead, we can just use it as so, `increment()` or `counter`

Comment: I know this question was asked a long time ago, but I am having trouble using counter. It will console.log() as 1, but when I actually try and use it, it is 0. Also making a function that returns counter doesn't work either.

Comment: Try and change `counter++` to `counter + 1`. @GIISE

Answer (score 2):

There is one hacky way to modify a `global.foo` variable.

Doesn't work

```
global.foo = 'foo'; //this cant be changed
global.foo = 'foofoo';
console.log(global.foo); //foo
```

Does work

```
global.foo = ['foo']; //this can be changed
global.foo[0] = 'foofoo';
console.log(global.foo[0]); //foofoo
```

Comment: Are you sure this would achieve the expected result?

Comment: Yes, the global.foo is assigned an array u cant change that but u can change what is inside the array

Comment: @Torped Thats Awesomely stated